# How to check if a program is mining crypto in the background

Tags: security

I noticed a program I recently downloaded cause my CPU usage increase by 30 percent and 80% GPU usage increment in idle state. It is not a GPU intensive program at all. I am worried about it using my computer to mine crypto. Is there a way to check this or find more direct evidences? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to check suspicious network traffic. Install `wireshark` and inspect all network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it performs intensive CPU operations and also if it does that regularly at peak and low intervals,
you can also disconnect the internet as mining requires downloading of tasks or hashes to brute force and also submit work to complete mining sub-task
You could also see its threads and see what is really happening
If the internet usage is lowered by throttling the cpu priority assigned or
by reducing its usable cpu capacity by some way,there are above 80% chances that its mining in background